# Is there a way to enter interactive mode after running a scala script from the command line? (equivalent to Python's `-i` option)

Tags: scala

In Python, you can pass an option to the interpreter so that dumps you into an interactive session once the script finishes executing.

```
python -i myscript.py
```

Once in interactive mode, you can then inspect the state and objects in your script. Is there a similar functionality with scala and the REPL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scala -i myscript.scala` should do the trick.

Comment: Well... I fell quite dumb. That definitely does work.. Thanks!